# HTML modal ajax form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send login form with phone number with ajax,but when I click the button its sending form( Refreshing the page) & AJAX not working.

My HTML (Login modal) :

```
            <div id="modal_new" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <form class="form-horizontal form-material" role="clientLogin" id="form" method="POST">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" style=" font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif; font-size: 17px; ">הזינו מספר טלפון נייד להזדהות</h4> </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div id="response"></div>
                                        <div id="redirect"></div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="num" class="form-control" name="phone_number" placeholder="0526476333" id="recipient-name"> 
                                                    </div>



                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:left;">
                                        <button type="button" style=" margin: 5px;font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif; " class="btn btn-outline-info" data-dismiss="modal">סגור</button>
                                        <button type="submit" style="font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;" class="btn btn-outline-success">התחבר</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

My JS :

```
    if ($("form[role=clientLogin]").length)
{
    $("form[role=clientLogin]").submit(function() {
        var url = $("#url").val();
        var data_url = url + "manage/sources/ajax/ajax.php?type=clientLogin";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: data_url,
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#response").html(data.msg);
                console.log(data.msg);
            if(data.status == "success") {
                $("#redirect").html(data.redirect);
            }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

I trying for hours,but failed.
I am sure its something with the form.

Comment: You trying it when submit button click?

Comment: Is there any error on the inspector when you send?

Comment: Try with this after your success event:
success: function(e) {
                //yourcode
            },
            error: function(e, t, a) {
                console.log(e)
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submit is called with an event object. If you call .preventDefault() on this, it should stop the default submit behaviour. eg.

```
$("form[role=clientLogin]").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```